# Rigidbody not colliding with procedural mesh plane element

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I have a cube with Rigid Body, box collider etc That falls through a plane with a procedural mesh script, the collision box stays the same as the default plane but the visually rendered mesh changes as it should.

[image: example1]
[image: example2]
[image: example3]
[image: example4]

Comment: Can you show the code for the Terrain Prefab Script? It is likely that you did not assign a mesh to the Mesh Collider, or did it at the wrong time.

Comment: Please post your code for the procedural mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Screenshot I can see you have the `Plane Instance` mesh assigned to the `MeshFilter` component, **but** in the `MeshCollider` the mesh is still set to `Plane`.

You are probably missing to assign it like e.g.

```
GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
```